# How to split a Blob along channels in Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I would like to split the Blob channels in Caffe, so that I can split one Blob of `(N, c, w, h)` into two output Blobs of size `(N, c/2, w, h)`.

What I have described above is very general, what I want to do actually is to separate a two-channel input image into two different images. One goes to a convolutional layer and the other goes to a pooling layer. Finally, I concatenate the outputs.

So I am wondering if a Caffe layer that allows the user to do such thing exists, and how to define it in the prototxt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `Slice` layer is for that purpose. From the [Layer Catalogue](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html):

> The `Slice` layer is a utility layer that slices an input layer to multiple output layers along a given dimension (currently `num` or `channel` only) with given slice indices.

To slice a Blob of size `N x 2 x H x W` into two Blobs of size `N x 1 x H x W`, you have to slice `axis: 1` (along channels) at `slice_point: 1` (after the first channel):

```
layer {
  name: "slice-conv-pool"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
  }
}
```