# Caffe: splitting input blob into multiple output blobs

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, conv-neural-network

I am aware of caffe split layer. But it act like copying the input and pasting as multiple identical outputs.

Here I am interested in slitting for example 1x30x40x60 input into three 1x10x40x60 or 1x30x40x20 outputs. is there such thing out there?

I need something like slice layer but with more than 1 cut point

Comment: How would you like to do that split? Simply take the first 15 dimensions in the first example or the first 25 dimensions in the second example? If so, you discard parts of the data... If you want some other way: where should the data be split?

Comment: I want something like k-fold cross-validation and then I give each fold into a separate layer.

Comment: you say "you discard parts of the data". how to do that? by multiplying that part to 0 and rest to 1 (just my naive guess)?

Comment: can slice do the job? (i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228315/how-to-split-a-blob-along-channels-in-caffe)

Comment: @NimaHatami yes. slice layer can slice into multiple slices

Comment: thanks @Shai should I delete this question or leave it like this?

Comment: @NimaHatami why delete? it's up to you to decide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: slice layer can slice into multiple slices